# Batch data processing from REST webservice in Android app

Tags: android

I want to download a subset of data from a WCF REST webservice to my android app. I want the app to hold onto this particular batch until the user has viewed it all. The user must swipe through each piece of data and then when you have run out of data, it should go to the webservice and get the next batch.

My webservice interface implements a GetBatch(int size, List IdsToRemove) method where you specify how many to return in a batch, also passing in a list of items that have now been processed by the user and can be removed from the queue before returning the next batch. This handles the webservice side of things fine.

What I am trying to work out, is how to save the returned items somewhere in my android app (they are complex Java objects with nested objects inside them) so that at any time, the user can open the app and return to where they were at with processing the batch, ie it remembers which ones have already been processed, and then when the last one has been processed, it re-calls the webservice passing in a list of ID's of the ones it has now processed, returns the next batch, deletes the old batch from storage and replaces with the new batch.

What is the best way of doing this in Android?

Edit: I assume the answer has two parts - Firstly how to keep the data stored application-wide while the app is open so it can be accessed rapidly when needed, and secondly how to store that data when the app goes out of context

Comment: It's coming down as JSON

Comment: R u processing huge number of data...?

Comment: You are talking of `they are complex Java objects` but what you get from the server is just text in json format. So just save as text.

Comment: I will be returning around 10 items of data, each one has about eight fields along with two nested complex objects (item category and user profile who created the item) along with a collection of "hashtags" that relate to that item. I create this as a complex Java object model so I can have an ArrayList<MyItem> which I bind to a pagerview to swipe through it. I guess what makes sense to me is to somehow store this ArrayList<MyItem> at a global application level while the app is running, and then serialise it out somewhere when the app pauses or stops, then reload it back in when it starts up

Comment: Parse JSONObjects and JSONArray into ArrayList<Object> store it in DB. Then display it, fetching from DB.

Comment: What is the latency of retrieving data from database, is it a high overhead? When I retrieve the JSON data from the webservice, I will write to the database but should I then extract into my complex object format and keep that at a global application level until the app closes, or should I just retrieve from the database every time I need to display the data? How bad performance wise would that be?

Comment: Or are you suggesting parse into my complex object hierachy first from JSON, then store those objects in the DB?

Comment: JSON data which you got is not too complex. Parsing JSON to ArrayList will be in millsec. So the insertion and fetching from DB in millisec only. Over all these opertion can be done in 1 to 2 sec... If u want much faster approach, then parse ur json into ArrayList and directly display it in list using ArrayAdapter, But this data wil not persist if user come back from that screen....

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there no application-wide global object I can hold the ArrayList in while the app is open? So when the user is switching between intents and fragments it loads from app memory fast, and only needs to write/read to DB when the app goes into sleep or close mode